# Algorithm to find best position

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the following problem. I have two mobile nodes (Green Circles) which can be moved on both X and Y axis. The mobile nodes connect the fixed nodes (Red Squares). I want to position the mobile nodes in an optimal position.

Optimal position can be calculated by determining the lowest total volume of the connector pipes. Each pipe has a height and cross section area.

For Example:
Total volume of MN1 = (150 * 7.5) + (100 * 10.0) + (250 * 15)
Total Volume of MN1 = 5875

If we move the MN1 in the direction of FN1, the total volume of MN1 will decrease and the total volume MN2 will increase. I need to find the optimal position for both MN1 and MN2. How to achieve this?[image: Pipes and Nodes]

Comment: This might be a nice question, but in its current form it's on the wrong site.

Comment: A few comments: (1) The volume is wrong. The volume of a pipe with radius `r` and height `h` is `h * pi * r * r`. Or do you mean the _area_? (2) This is a minimization problem in calculus, of four variables if you are restricted in 2D, or six if 3D.

Comment: Also, the weight function is missing. If you want to optimize somehting, you need a criteria to optimize against. You do not specify, how (exactly) the weights are calculated.

Comment: The weight is the sum over the pipes of their length times their radius. Anyway, any gradient descent implementation will do.

Comment: Corrected the description. Changed radius to cross section area.